# Sherlock action bar action icons have wrong size / dpi

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use SherlockActionBar to get the ICS look to older devices. On a Optimus Black P970 (800x480) I get different icon sizes.
The 2nd and 4th icon are hdpi icons, so this is correct but why does sherlock provide mdpi/ldpi icons?

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_save"
    android:title="@string/menu_save"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_today"
    android:title="@string/menu_today"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_calendar"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
```

[image: Action bar]

Comment: Have you putted all icons in hdpi, mdpi and in ldpi also??

Comment: actually you are using native image from android.jar @android:drawable/ic_menu_save" this is fine. Can you show the layout how you are using image view.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple icon sizes (for now just hdmi and default). I just inflate the menu to show it in the action bar.

Comment: I'm facing similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124343/actionbarsherlock-leads-to-icons-get-stretched), have you managed to solve it?